# ajax page refresh once loading page has finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i have this js/ajax code:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); // This part addresses an IE bug. without it, IE will only load the first number and will never refresh
    setInterval(function() {
        $('.container').load('/copy/copy.php');
    }, 4000);
});
// ]]></script>

<div class="container"></div>
```

but i need to make sure the 'copy.php' has fully loaded until it refreshes again

Answer (score 1):

The [`.load()` function](https://api.jquery.com/load/) provides a callback to use once the loading has completed:

```
$('.container').load('/copy/copy.php', function(){
 // the load has completed successfully. 
});
```

Use this callback to initiate the reloading of the content.

Comment: where does the rest of my code go? how to i refresh the page?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a recursive-ish `setTimeout` instead:

```
function refreshContent() {
    $.get('/copy/copy.php').done(function (content) {
        $('.container').html(content);
    }).always(function () {
        setTimeout(refreshContent, 4000);
    });
}
```

This way, the 4 second timer won't start until the call has finished.

Comment: this isn't refreshing the copy.php page at all

Comment: So, you do have to call the function once.. did you do that?

Comment: no i didn't, I'm not too familiar with javascript. how do i call it?